# $_SESSION messages not displaying

Tags: php

Please, I dont know what might be the problem that my $_SESSION['error'] does not display in my html file. I dont see what might be the problem.
I have error messages in session but none of them displays

in my html, i included my backend code that is php and session is started there

```
//HTML FILE
register.php
<? php
 require_once 'php.php';

?>


<h4>Registration</h4>

                    <div><?php 
    
          if ( isset($_SESSION['error']) ) {
            echo '<p style="color:red">'.$_SESSION['error']."</p>\n";
            unset($_SESSION['error']);
        }
        if ( isset($_SESSION['success']) ) {
            echo '<p style="color:green">'.$_SESSION['success']."</p>\n";
            unset($_SESSION['success']);
        }       

                                        
                ?>
                </div>
       
                    <form action="about.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          
        
                    <p id="head"></p>
          <!-- <div class="mb-3"> -->
                        <label for="surname" class="form-label">Surname</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="surname" name="surname" 

                        <label for="firstname" class="form-label">First name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="<?= htmlentities($firstname) ?>" required>
                    

                        <label for="othername" class="form-label">Othername</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="othername" name="othername" value="<?= htmlentities($othername) ?>"><br>
<button type="submit" id="submitform" name="signup-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-inline-block btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
        </form>




//PHP 

<?php
session_start();
require_once "pdo.php";



if (isset($_POST['signup-btn'])) {
    
    if (strlen($_POST['surname']) < 1) {
         $_SESSION['error']          = "Please, add surname";
        header("Location:register.php");
        return;
    }

    if (strlen($_POST['firstname']) < 1) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Please, add your first name";
        header("Location:register.php");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Please add session_start(); into your view/html file as well. 

if still not work then Please let me know that with $_SESSION['success'] works or not? 
if both are not working then might be a server issue.

Comment: @FawadSaboor i included my php in the html file. and it uses the the session. both success and error is not working. I have hosted the web live and still it doesnt show.

Comment: did we add session_start(); inside php.php please share php.php code too.

Comment: @FawadSaboor yes, session is started in php.php. sorry i dont know that the code was hiding before

Answer (score 1):

The **session_start** must be before any HTML is emitted.  In the file, you have **<h4>** before session_start is executed.

Shift the **session_start** to the top of the file.  If **php.php** has no HTML then it can be after the **include**, otherwise, put it before the include.

Comment: thanks for your help, php.php has no html code. it is purely for php code. Even at this, i have placed session_start on top of everything in php.php file. what i have now is <?php session_start ..... but still, it is not showing session['..'] messages.

Comment: There cant be any echo statements either as they produce html.

Comment: i dont understand what you are trying to say

Comment: Sorry, my error, ignore that comment.  I see that you are checking for **'signup-btn'** but there is no button in the code that you have shown.

Comment: there is. I didnt add it coz i didnt add all my codes. it is too long to add. Every thing is working. signup, login etc but to display messages for success or error for users is a problem.

Comment: The session_start was definitely a problem.  Maybe your sessions are disabled.  Look at the result of session_start.

Comment: How do i look at the result of session_start or see if it is disabled? If i do login, it logs in, session variables are set perfectly. everything works except messages for error or success.